# Boto3 pass json as argument

Tags: python, boto3

When looking at the boto3 documentation, the list of arguments that the ECS run_task (or other methods for that matter) takes looks like a json. So my thought is that if I have a json document, I could use that instead of hardcoding my parameters. However, the below yields a `TypeError: run_task() only accepts keyword arguments.`

Here is my input

```
cluster: om2-cluster-CRIMB-CRIMSOM2-internal
taskDefinition: om2-om2*
count: 1
launchType: FARGATE
overrides:
  containerOverrides:
      environment:
        - name: bucket
          value: theBucketName
        - name: key
          value: TheKeyName
```

And here is my code

```
runCommand = yaml.load(runTaskYaml, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
response = client.run_task(json.dumps(runCommand))
```

Comment: have you tried `response = client.run_task(**runCommand)`?

Comment: Well I'm getting an invalid type for parameter 'overrides', BUT I believe that solves my problem. Thank you so much and obviously I need to learn Python a bit better :)

Comment: no problem and best of luck!